# Don't you dare to play sports over my dead body

Tags: riddle

> *Names I've been given by different people:*
>   Some said I've many
>   faces, some said I'm blue, others said i'm fire.
>
> *Where I can be found:*
>   You can find me on a map, on a table, or, on a
>   winning streak!
>
> *How do you find me:*
>   You can go travel.  You can also be good at
>   knocking things down.  Oh yeah, be thanksful too.

In fact, I will see you soon.  But please, stop rolling me around...

What am I?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is

> Turkey

Names I've been given by different people:
Some said I've many faces, some said I'm blue, others said i'm fire.

> literal translations: 
>  Japanese and Korean: "seven-faced bird"
>  Some Turkic languages: "blue bird" 
>  Mandarin: "fire chicken"

Where I can be found:
You can find me on a map, on a table, or, on a winning streak!

> Turkey is a country, a food, and a term for three strikes in a row in bowling.

How do you find me:
You can go travel. You can also be good at knocking things down. Oh yeah, be thanksful too.

> You can go to the country. You can get a "turkey" in bowling. And you'll find it at a Thanksgiving dinner.

Don't you dare to play sports over my dead body

> I think this is referring to the playing of professional sports (namely NFL football) on Thanksgiving Day.

Comment: Correct!  The title and the last sentence refers to [Turkey Bowling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turkey_bowling) as well